# Show whether $K\cap F^c$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $K$ compact and $F$ closed. Determine if $K\cap F^c$ is definitely closed, definitely compact, both, or neither.

I already have that $K\cap F^c$ is bounded due to the fact that $K$ is bounded and $K\cap F^c \subseteq K$. I am trying to see whether it is closed or not, if someone could please provide assistance.

Comment: yes i do sorry!!

Comment: @Hawk The complement  is *not* the union of two open sets, since $F$ is closed (not open).

Comment: Hint: $[0,2]$ is compact and $[1,3]$ is closed. What can you say about  $[0,1)$?

Comment: I don't remember, probably not. I didn't read carefully, I must've thought it was the typical problem.